# Split last column into two equal halves in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I need to split last column into two separate columns & delete some part of it.

Currently all the values in the last column has 6 numbers . I need to split them into two separate columns. 
First column should have first three numbers and second column should have next three numbers.

I ultimately want to delete newly created second column.

```
Data - 
ID c1 c2 c3  c4  c5
12 A  XY 123 456 657098
```

The new file should be created as below -

```
Data 2
ID c1 c2 c3  c4  c5
12 A  XY 123 456 657
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk` that checks length of last column for each row:

```
awk 'length($NF) == 6 { $NF = substr($NF, 1, 3) } 1' file

Data  -
ID    c1  c2  c3   c4   c5
12    A   XY  123  456  657
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava , how can i create a new file from the same command deleting that C5 ?

Comment: `awk 'length($NF) == 6 { $NF = substr($NF, 1, 3) } 1' file > newFile` would do the job